# jQuery functionality not working after POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post

I have this simple `select` element, which is wrapped in a form:

```
<form id="createSomething" method="post" action="/same_page.php">
    <select id="selectService" class="form-control mt-2" name="service">
        <option selected value="a">Select...</option>
        <option value="b">Something</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This jQuery code works fine, when I initially load the page via a `GET` request:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectService").on("change", function() {
    window.alert( "TEST" );
    });
});
```

But when I submit the form via a `POST` request (the same page with the same jQuery is loaded),

my jQuery does not work anymore. Why is that so and how can I make it work?

Comment: Use "change" attribute

Comment: If you have button type submit it will post your page (which is same as refresh so your js will never run) you need to use `$("#selectService").on("submit", function() { return false; });` to prevent POST request.

Comment: Or (to @jcubic comment) change your button so it doesn't submit: `<button type="button">...`

Comment: @subhan I was using `change` - I just made a mistake when uploaded the question (because I was playing around). Sorry for that.

Comment: How do you initially load your jquery code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#selectService", function() {
    window.alert( "TEST" );
    });
```

Maybe that's the answer as I understand your requirement.